Can someone post a question on staging-ground while question banned?
Can someone post a question on staging-ground while question banned? I imagine they could, and can't check it myself.

No they can't, but I specifically asked for the feature for them to be able to be added.

I am quite sure that the Staging Ground doesn't bypass question bans, there were talks to allow question banned users to go through the staging ground but I believe that's not something implemented yet. I won't answer this though and let staff confirm on this.

Why was this question downvoted? This is a simple question so there is nothing to 'disagree' with here.

A lot of those votes were against the original revision, @Cplus .

Even if the other one is newer, I think we can now mark this as a duplicate of Send users in a question ban to the Staging Ground when asking a question.

No, they cannot. It was requested a few times (I was an advocate to allow it), such as in the Private Teams and in response to the announcement the SG was returning. In response to that answer Slate states:

This concept of using Staging Ground to help people escape question bans has been brought up internally. For now, we've decided that the focus of Staging Ground is on the new user experience, rather than aiding askers who are already question blocked.

So this may change in the future, but we have no details of if/when at this time.

Pity. Your "users struggle to get out of said bans, having them go through the SG could greatly help them" is a good point I hadn't even considered.

It's not clear to me why the "new user experience" wouldn't be automatically helpful as-is to people who were q-banned - i.e. why anything would have to change besides the rule for admission.

That's a question for Slate and/or others involved in the SG, @KarlKnechtel . It, probably, would be a good question to be asked on it's own; though you'd have to hope that a Staff member actually read the question...

I like the idea, hopefully it will implemented after the initial SG experience is digested.

I think they should be allowed, because many of the question banned people might not be question banned in the first place if they started when there was Staging Ground to keep them from asking questions that get super poorly received.

Seems like, perhaps, I should get the ol' [[meta-tag:feature-request]] out.
